# Machine Learning Predictors Evaluation Using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models

I've bee using R for predicitve analytics and here is issue: I'm trying to predict the species (categorical variables E1, E2, E3 and E4) of an animal using as predictors a set of nominal (NO1, NO2, NO3, NO4 and NO5) and numeric (NU1, NU2 and NU3) features. For that I used a few different methods: Naive Bayes, Decision Trees, Support Vector Machines and Multinomial Logit.

I'd like to know if there is a way to evaluate (quantify or qualify) the importance/impact of each predictor I use either before or after prediction is done, something that would tell me, for instancem that, say, NO3, NO4 and NU2 aren't good in predicting the species but the other predictors are.

Many thanks in Advance.

Diego.